# Необходимо ли папки 'packages' в C# проекте хранить в git-репозитории проекта?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

У меня есть два два проекта `HelloWorld` и `HelloWorld.UnitTests`. Во втором применив `nuget` я установил `NUnit`, в результате чего создана папка `packages`. Использую Visual Studio 2013.

Сейчас репозиторий выглядит так:

```
.\HelloWorld\
.\HelloWorld.UnitTests\
.\HelloWorld.UnitTests\packages.config
.\packages\
.\HelloWorld.sln
```

Папка `packages` появилась после того как сделал активным проект `HelloWorld.UnitTests` и применил команду `Install-Package NUget` в консоли.

В Python-е, есть так называемые файлы зависимостей и можно применить команду `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Но в C# такого решения не нашел. Меня смущает, что видимо придется хранить множество dll-файлов, хотя логичнее было бы в репозитории хранить файл зависимостей, аналогичный python-овскому решению с `requirements.txt` файлом.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что мне все-таки придется эту папку хранить в репозитории проекта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Основной способ подключения/удаления зависимостей в проект является nuget. В папке проекта у вас должен быть файл packages.config. В нем хранятся данные об используемых в проекте nuget-пакетах. Добавлять в VCS нужно именно его. На основании содержащихся в нем данных будут скачаны необходимые пакеты. Dll'ки же включать необязательно. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @sys_dev если после клонирования у вас не будет каких то пакетов, то щелкнуть правой кнопкой мышки по папке референсов в студии, выбрать управление пакетами nuget, далее скачать недостающие

Comment: @Dmitry: Я задаю этот вопрос, который достаточно легко гуглится не для того чтобы решить свою задачу. А для того чтобы этот вопрос раз и навсегда ЗАКРЫТЬ! Именно по этой причине и прошу дать ясные и недвусмысленные ответы

Comment: @sys_dev я ответил на вопрос который вы задавали в комментарии и потом удалили его, пока я писал свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Для.Net проектов есть nuget. Он создает файл, подобный питоновскому requirements.txt с зависимостями, и умеет их самостоятельно востанавливать.